# Replace URI prefix from Base64String using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, jszip

I'm working with [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) download and there are some photo URI data which should be downloaded by [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/).

Photo URI looks like this:

```
photouri1 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9a...';
photouri2 = 'data:image/png;base64,/9a...';
```

As you see, there are 2 types of photo URIs. Since `zip.file` api requires data to be base64String, I should replace URI prefix with empty string as follows:

```
...
var base64Str1 = photouri1.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '');
zip.file('image1', base64Str1, { base64: true });
var base64Str1 = photouri1.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
zip.file('image2', base64Str2, { base64: true });
zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then(...)
```

I want that *replacing operation* could be done at a time(**batch operation**) using a simple **regex** with for~loop.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use this `.*(?=\/)`

Comment: @CodeManiac would u provide a detailed statement?

Comment: yeah sure added this as answer with detailed explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can try this**

```
^.*base64,(?=\/)
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `.*` - Will match anything except newline character zero or more time.(Greedy mode).
- base64,`- Will match`base64,`.
- `(?=\/)` - Positive lookahead will match `/`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rOKsdj/3)

Comment: thanks a lot. i did it like this.  `str = photouri.replace(/^.*base64,(?=\/)/, '');`

Comment: @RobJS always happy to help :)